# number parsing in awk

Tags: awk

I have a text file with numbers in second column and the numbers have thousand-separator and decimal-separator:

```
2014-01     2,277.40
2014-02     2,282.20
2014-03     3,047.90
2014-04     4,127.60
2014-05     5,117.60
```

I need to sum the numbers, but the following `awk` syntax does not work:

```
awk '{X=X+$2} END {print X}' file
```

It returns `16`, which is obviously wrong. How can I tell `awk` to read the number as `2277.40` instead of `2,277.40`?

Comment: Why not simply say: `tr -d ',' < file | awk '{X=X+$2} END {print X}'`?

Comment: In fact, `gawk` (which is aliased as `awk` on many systems today) has an option `--use-lc-numeric` which works for parsing the decimal point, so in fact you could use `LC_NUMERIC=en_US gawk --use-lc-numeric ...`. Unfortunatelly this does NOT work for parsing thousand separator, despite it is also part of the `LC_NUMERIC` setting (quite confusing). So you have to resort to one of "dirty" workarounds below. I would consider this an gawk bug though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that although you need to remove the commas from your input before adding the values to your total, but `awk` is happy to print your results with or without thousands separators. As an example, if you use the following code: look at `fmt` variable defined in code.

Your Input :

```
$ cat file
2014-01     2,277.40
2014-02     2,282.20
2014-03     3,047.90
2014-04     4,127.60
2014-05     5,117.60
```

Awk Code :

```
$ awk '{gsub(/,/,"",$2);sum+=$2}END{printf(fmt,sum)}' fmt="%'6.3f\n" file
```

Resulting :

```
16,852.700
```

If you want to try this on a `Solaris/SunOS` system, change `awk` at the start of this script to `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` ,`/usr/xpg6/bin/awk` , or `nawk` .

Hope this will be useful.

Comment: Very nice awk formatting trick.

Comment: I get following error on my Debian machine: `awk: run time error: improper conversion(number 1) in printf("%'6.3f`

Answer (score 12):

Just remove the commas from the field you're parsing:

```
awk '{sub(",", "", $2); X+=$2} END {print X}' file
```

This started as a quick-and-dirty solution, but it seems like there actually is no other way. From the [AWK Manual](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_65.html):

> A string is converted to a number by interpreting a numeric prefix of the string as numerals: "2.5" converts to 2.5, "1e3" converts to 1000, and "25fix" has a numeric value of 25. Strings that can't be interpreted as valid numbers are converted to zero.

And while the format for number-to-string conversion can be set via the `CONVFMT` variable, there is no such option for string-to-number conversions.<sup>[[1]](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_100.html)</sup>

---

Even [`gawk`'s strtonum()](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Strtonum-Function.html), while honoring the decimal separator defined by the system's locale, ignores (i.e. cuts off at) thousand-separators.

Comment: I was going to comment with that same awk manual snippet, when I noticed the "This post has been edited" on top. +1, I think this answer should be accepted.

Comment: this doesn't work for many locales

Answer (score 3):

I like using `bc` for things like this. Granted you're only adding but this pattern is useful if you need to do more sophisticated things that require `bc` for doing the calculations.

```
$ paste -s -d+ <(awk '{gsub(/,/,"",$2); print $2}' sample.txt) | bc
16852.70
```

Comment: Why invoke `awk` to remove the comma and not have it do the math? What complicated math can `bc` do that `awk` (or gnu awk) can't?

Comment: @RickyBeam - base conversions is a big one. I find `awk` a sloppy language being another, and I use Perl daily. When developing my code in `bc` it's a lot easier to debug it vs. debugging an `awk` script. This is obviously my opinion, but the above pattern is easier to use to solve a variety of problems vs. having to custom craft `awk` solutions that feel more one off to me. Is that enough to justify your DV?

Answer (score 3):

@Martin Vegter it must be `mawk` so you are getting error, see I can produce same error

```
[akshay@aix tmp]$ awk -vfmt="%'6.3f\n" 'BEGIN{sum=12052255;printf(fmt,sum)}'
12,052,255.000

[akshay@aix tmp]$ mawk -vfmt="%'6.3f\n" 'BEGIN{sum=12052255;printf(fmt,sum)}'
mawk: run time error: improper conversion(number 1) in printf("%'6.3f")
FILENAME="" FNR=0 NR=0

[akshay@aix tmp]$ which awk
/bin/awk

[akshay@aix tmp]$ which mawk
/usr/bin/mawk
```

Install `gawk` and try

Comment: yes, it is `/usr/bin/mawk` on my system. Is there any way to make it work with `mawk` rather that changing to `gawk` ?

Comment: @MartinVegter : Actually `mawk` is a minimal-featured `awk` designed for speed of execution over functionality. You should not expect it to behave exactly the same as `gawk` or a `POSIX awk`, infact `mawk` has got lots of bug also, if ubuntu user you can easily install using `sudo apt-get install gawk` if `rhel/centos/fedora` you can use `yum` or `rpm` packages